# Static initializations in multithreaded program

Tags: c++, c++11, ctypes

I've come across a wierd problem porting a shared library from windows to linux (CentOS 7.2).

The library is used in a python web app and is being run in a multithreaded environment.

There are no problems with the library when I run it on windows (compiled with visual studio 2015) but it crashes (segfaults) on linux when run with several threads. I could not reproduce the crash on linux with only one thread.

The library loads data into maps in initialization methods. Later, when the other threads tries to access the maps it cannot read the memory the maps are pointing to.

The following is one of the methods used to access the maps. The idea is that the first time it is called it initialize the map which is then populated with data. For the consecutive calls it simply returns a pointer to the map and the data can be extracted.

```
map<string, Airport*>& getIataAirports (){
    static auto iata_airports = new map<string, Airport*>;
    return *iata_airports;
}
```

When the thread enters this method it all looks well and good.

```
(gdb)p *iata_airports
$1 = std::map with 8763 elements = {["ARN"] = 0x7f34d0b3b8d8,...
```

But in the method where it gets used it doesnt work:

```
airport_t* getAirportByIATA(const char *iata) {
    string iata_s{iata};
    auto it = getIataAirports().find(iata_s);
    if (it != getIataAirports().end())
        return AS_C_AIRPORT(it->second);
    else
        return nullptr;
}
```

Debugging through the code the find method returns an iterator which is not the end of the map but the value of the it->second is a bogus value.

```
(gdb)p it
$2 = {first ="ARN", second = }

(gdb) p &(it->second)
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
```

What could be the reason for this behavour? Note again that it works perfectly on windows (and singlethreaded in linux).

On linux the library was compiled (without warnings) with g++ 4.8.5 and the following flags.
-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pthread -g -O2

And it is loaded dynamically with python's ctype cdll.loadLibrary method.

Any hints on how to continue debugging this behaviour is greatly appreciated!

**Update**:

Thanks for all suggestions so far.

I haven't been able to reproduce this error in pure c++. I tried calling the initialize method in a thread, wait for it until it's complete, and then access the library in a different thread and it works without problems.

I now think it's related to the library being loaded in a python thread.

The webserver handles each requests in separate thread. The library is initialized lazily meaning it gets loaded when used the first time. Because of this design the library will then be loaded and initialized in a thread handling the first response to the server (i.e., not in the main thread). Then, for some reason, when the next thread is going to access data the process crashes. Again only on linux, it works fine on windows. I will compile a python 2.7.11 version on linux and see if it could be python versions that is the culprit here.

**Update 2**

I should add that I manage to get it working by initialising the library in the main thread of the webserver. I still want to figure out why it doesn't work the way it does on windows though.

Comment: You're certain the initialization methods run before the threads reading the data do?  The threads only read the data and don't modify it?

Comment: Why do you think the initialization is the problem? Are you modifying the `map` in one thread and reading it in another? If yes, you need to protect it using a mutex. And why are you `new`ing the `map`? `static map<string, Airport*> iata_airports; return iata_airports;` works too.

Comment: `getIataAirports`  doesn't seem a thread-safe method; are multiple threads calling it ? Why create the map every time it is called ?

Comment: @perencia - `iata_airports` is `static`, so it only gets initialized the first time the function is called. That's threadsafe starting with C++11, and maybe with some compilers before then.

Comment: minimal complete example please?

Comment: The map is not modified after initialisation so it should be thread safe. I'll try to make a minimal complete example tomorrow (though it's quite hard to mimic the runtime behaviour as its being called in a multithreaded Python web server).

Comment: You could have problems if two threads call `getAirportByIATA` at the same time. While one is constructing a new map, the other is returning the static one just created. As suggested, in C++11 static initialization is thread safe, just do it as: `static map<string, Airport*> iata_airports;` otherwise you'll end up having problems.

Comment: @dau_sarma isn't the initialization done just once?

Comment: You can have `map<string, Airport*>` as a global variable, there is no apparent reason to construct it on the first call.

Comment: I actually used global variables first but ran into the 'static initialisation order fiasco':
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order

Comment: I'm not sure i fully understand the situation: You are calling C++ code from a multithreaded Python program. Are you then using any threads inside the C++ code? I can vaguely remember mixing Python and C++ threads causing me some trouble once.